# Creating a template class such that subclasses inherit parameters from parent in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some questions here. I'm trying to optimize my code and using line_profiler have found that the majority of my time is spent on class instantiation. Now here's a summary of what I'm trying to do and how I got here.

I have three classes: Template, Individual, Collective, set up roughly as such: (Not the actual code, but close enough to establish a more concrete idea of what I'm trying to do

```
class Template:
      def __init__(self, param_boundaries):
          self.param_boundaries = param_boundaries

class Individual(Template):
      def __init__(self, i_params, template):
          self.i_params = i_params
          self.template = template

      def method_example(self):
          #modifies i_params based on self.template.param_boundaries

class Collective:
      def __init__(self, n, template):
          #creates n random Individuals using the Template
```

line_profiler shows that the biggest hurdle is the line self.template = template. And really, even if that wasn't the case it's taking up more memory than it needs to by saving the entirety of the template inside each Individual. My question is whether there's a way to simply reference the parameters passed into Template from Individual without having to save Template in the Individual dictionary.

A few things that might be useful:
1) Template will NOT be modified at all after it is instantiated.
2) Individuals do NOT communicate with each other
3) Collective only uses Template to generate Individuals
4) I am using Python 3.7

Please let me know if any additional information is required, or if this is a duplicate. To be quite honest, I don't really have the vocabulary to really search what it is that I am trying to do. I've tried to look for things before posting, but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: No that is not what is happening. Assignment never creates a copy, all that is happening is that a new reference is being created to the template object. That is not the source of your problem.

Comment: can you please show an example of how these classes are being used? Simply the definitions isn't very helpful.

Comment: I see. Perhaps my interpretation of line_profiler's output was incorrect. Since as far as I'm aware it doesn't work with class initialization I created a dummy object to work around this limitation and that's how I got that line_profiler spent most of its time on the self.template assignment. There has to be other factors at play that I'm unaware of then.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I can't share the actual code since I don't want to get in trouble with my workplace's strict policies, but what I can share is that it is an implementation of a genetic algorithm. The template stores the boundaries, the crossover mutation and fitness functions, booleans, the works. Each individual then references these when "mating" or mutating. The Collective is just the pool of individuals and handles parent selection among other things.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. You must be specific, your descriptions are much too high level and generic to be of any use. You should *never* be sharing your whole code. Instead, craft a [mcve] that reproduces your problem. You don't have to reveal any actual business logic for that. But you do have to give an example of what you are actually doing.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is your problem here? Each individual instance already just references the template. Referencing each parameter directly would take up more space, because that would require more references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you had not understand enough of the concept of inheritance in Object Oriented approaches (and he way it works in Python) -

WHen you inherit from `Template` your derived classes *are* a "Template" as well, besides being extended or refined in whatever code you write in the child-class bodies.

If "template" can be held in an attribute, then you are looking at class composition, which is generally easier to understand and work with than inheritance.

To proper use iheritance, however, any methods that you want to work well need to call the corresponding superclass method - In Python it is done with the demi-magic built-in `super` - Your code would look like:

```
class Template:
      def __init__(self, param_boundaries):
          self.param_boundaries = param_boundaries

class Individual(Template):
      def __init__(self, i_params, param_boundaries):
          self.i_params = i_params
          super().__init__(param_boundaries)


      def method_example(self):
          #modifies i_params based on self.template.param_boundaries

class Collective:
      def __init__(self, n, param_boundaries):
          super().__init__(param_boundaries)
          #creates n random Individuals using the Template
```

So - your "Individual" and "Collective" classesm being at the same type a type of "Template" do have a `.param_boundaries` attribute, which is created in the `Template.__init__` function, to be reached using the `super()...` call.

If you want both to have a "template" attribute which is a "Template" class instead, they should not inherit from `Template`, and just be declared like:

```py
class Individual:
      def __init__(self, i_params, template):
          self.i_params = i_params
          self.template = template
```

Then it will work without any unexpected surprises.

As for the "hurdle" in `self.template = template` line: that can't happen! 
All Python is doing is creating a new reference to the already built object, and it is as trivial as it can be - if it is indeed listed on your profile as taking more resources than anything else, what you are seeing in the profiler is just noise (i.e. values so low that will vary from run to run, and if they do not, they still can't be made any faster in Python code), and there is nothing you can optimize there *at all*.

Comment: You are correct on many fronts. I am entirely self-taught, and I double checked and yeah, turns out it was noise since it gave me different results every time. As it turns out I had programmed something wrong that for some reason I kept overlooking every time for days, it's embarrassing frankly.